# Why does $u$(vector) have to equal to $(f'_x,f'_y)$ which is the Directional derivative to get max value?

Tags: calculus

Given function $f(x,y)$, I need to find vector $u$ that will make $f'_u$ get its max value.

Why does $u$ have to equal to $(f'_x(M_0),f'_y(M_0))$ which is the Directional derivative to  get max value?

$M_0$ is a specific point.

(Then I need to find the norm of this, which I understand)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$.  Suppose that $f$ achieves its maximum value at a point $(x_0,y_0)$.  Consider the function $g(t) := f(t,y_0)$.  Then $g$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and achieves a maximum value at $x_0$, hence $g'(x_0) = 0$.  But $g'(x_0) = f_x(x_0,y_0)$.

Argue similarly in the other variable to see that if $f$ has a maximum value, it must be where $f_x (x_0,y_0) = 0 = f_y(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't conclude from this what I've asked. But thank you for the answer anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is asking about the gradient. Let $f(x,y)$ be a scalar function i.e $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ then we define the directional derivative of $f$ at $P$ (in the direction $u$, assume unit vector) to be;

$$\\$$

$$D_uf(P) = \lim_{t \to 0}\  \frac{f(P+tu) - f(P)}{t} = \frac{d}{dt} f(c(t))|_{t = 0}$$

where $c(t) = \vec{P} + t u$.

$$\\$$

Recall that by the chain rule for paths;

$$\\$$

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(c(t))|_{t=0} = \nabla f(P) \cdot c'(0) = \nabla f(P) \cdot u$$

Therefore you have;

$$\\$$

$$D_uf(P) = \nabla f(P) \cdot u = \|\nabla f(P)\| \|u\| \cos \theta = \|\nabla f(P)\| \cos \theta$$

$$\\$$

Now since $-1 \leq \cos \theta \leq 1$ then you have $D_uf(P)$ is maximum when $D_uf(P) = \|\nabla f(P)\|$ i.e in the direction of the gradient. Now since; $\nabla f(P) = \langle f_x(P), f_y(P) \rangle$,you have your desired result.